# Why Stylesheet doesn't work with QtGui in tableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5

I will try to be simple and direct.
if i create a tablewidget in qtDesign and add a stylesheet

```
QTableWidget:item{
color:#ffffff;
border:none;
margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

and when adding an item to the table and trying to use QtGui's Foreground or Background it doesn't work

```
item.setForeground(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255)))
```

however if I remove the stylesheet completely and not just the part color:#ffffff; it works normally

the question is does one not work if you have the other? and if it works where is the error?

I looked in the documentation and found nothing.

Comment: Setting the stylesheet completely overrides the item background and foreground roles. Use an item delegate instead.